# How to get the database binded dropdownlist item in a label in C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I did this in separate program but when I bind the data from database and retrieve in dropdown it works fine but when I click on submit button I want to get the data I have selected in dropdownlist show in a label...

I use the same method:

```
label.text = dropdownlist.selecteditem.text;
```

but it only prints the first item of dropdownlist, not the item which I selected.

For example:

> Australia 
>  england 
> russia
> Africa

When I selected England, the label shows Australia the result is same in selection of Russia and Africa too.

Comment: Can you show your code and provide more details like where you wrote that line of code?

Comment: We need to see your code which binds data from database to the dropdown list. Are you doing this in page_load and inside `if(!IsPostBack)` ??

Comment: (Please do not post in all-lower case here. If you are posting from a mobile phone and that is the reason for not using capital letters as appropriate, please find a laptop or a PC to post from. Thanks).

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like this..i am just writing the code for your information ,use the proper method to avoid the injection u know

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"YOUR CONNECTION STRING");
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNTRY FROM COUNTRIES", con);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    DropDownList1.Items.Add(dr["COUNTRY "].ToString());
                }
                dr.Close();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
```